# issues with the validation code one is running and other one not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {
    return this.attr(name) !== undefined;
  };
});

function hasValue(elem) {
  return $(elem).filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).length > 0;
}

if (hasValue("#Account")) {
  $("#Account").removeAttr('required');
  $("#AccountError").css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  return true;
} else {
  if ($("#Account").hasAttr('required')) {
    $("#Account").focus();
    $("#AccountError").css({
      'display': 'block',
      'color': 'red'
    }).html("Please select a valid  Account.");
    return false;
  }
}

if (hasValue("#PDF")) {
  $("#PDF").removeAttr('required');
  $("#PDFError").css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  return true;
} else {
  if ($("#PDF").hasAttr('required')) {
    $("#PDF").focus();
    $("#PDFError").css({
      'display': 'block',
      'color': 'red'
    }).html("Please upload only PDF file.");
    return false;
  }
}

var e = document.getElementById("StatusID");
e.onchange = function() {
  changeHandler();
};

window.onload = function() {
  changeHandler();
};

function changeHandler() {
  var _c = document.getElementById('TTS').value;
  var e = document.getElementById("StatusID");
  if (!$(e).is("select")) {
    var strUser = e.value;
  } else {
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  }
  if (_c == 0 && strUser == 7) {
    $(".Star").css('display', 'inline-block');
    document.getElementById('Account').setAttribute("required", "");
    document.getElementById('PDF').setAttribute("required", "");
  } else {
    $(".Star").css('display', 'none');
    document.getElementById('Account').removeAttribute("required");
    document.getElementById('PDF').removeAttribute("required");
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the `changeHandler` code runs it basically catches two conditions and if those are yes it adds the required attribute.

Now the problem is when it runs that code and submits the button, only the first one which is Account is validated when I provided a value to it, it never goes to the second validation.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share your code through the code snippet.

Comment: You have a `return true` (/false) in your first `if`(/else) so it never gets to your second `if`.

Comment: You also have invalid "code" `if(_c == 0 && strUser ==  and submits the form7) {`  - check the browser for errors and add either step through your code with a debugger or add copious (useful) `console.log()` lines in strategic places (like before each `if`)

Comment: @freedomn-m that was a typo mistake, why will add a string of text in the condition, that makes nosense 
 so you mean the first if should not return false and then it should go the second if

Comment: to me that comment does not make sense, because the text of the second statement does not shown, even the display:block is set, but text is not visible

Comment: The problem is that you've only provided a sample of code.  As provided, your `if (hasValue("#Account")) {` runs at the top level of the script, ie only once.  You state "submits the button, it runs the first [if/validation]" - but the *provided* code doesn't do this.  Perhaps you could provide a *complete* snippet that shows how these are put together, then we can show you how you are exiting from your validation in the first check so that it doesn't get to the second.   Or you could step through with the debugger and see what's happening for yourself.

Comment: See this page: [mcve]